# Filtering table via dropdown menu. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a real estate listings site and give the user the ability to filter by agent and suburb. Currently I'm getting the following message:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql1' at line 1"
Currently I'm only focusing on getting the first filter working which is "J Blades" in the agents drop down, which is why the others are incomplete or completely wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Pharcourts</title>
<link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

```
<div id="container">

<div id="container-background">


    <div id="header">


    <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="listings"><a href="staffornot.php">Listings</a></li>
                <li class="agents"><a href="agents.php">Agents</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php">About/Contact</a></li>
                <li class="login"><a href="login.php">Staff Login</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>


    </div>


    <div id="sidebar">

        <h2>On This Page:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#listings">Listings</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>


    <div id="content">


        <a id="listings"></a>
        <h1>Current Listings:</h1>
        <h3><a href='logout.php'>Logout<a></h3>

    <?php

        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("Location:Login.php");
        }

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysqli_error());
        mysqli_select_db($con,"alexdb") or die(mysqli_error());

        Print "<form action='listingsstaff.php' method='post'>";

        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tblhousingstock WHERE agent='J Blades'";

        Print "Agent";
        Print "<select name='filteragent'>";
        Print "<option value='SELECT * FROM tblhousingstock'>All</option>";
        Print '<option value="$sql1")>J Blades</option>';
        Print "<option value='SELECT * FROM tblhousingstock WHERE agent=D Astle'>D Astle</option>";
        Print "<option value='SELECT * FROM tblhousingstock WHERE agent=M Smith'>M Smith</option>";
        Print "</select>";


        Print "Suburb";

        $data1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tblhousingstock.add2 FROM tblhousingstock GROUP BY tblhousingstock.add2") or die(mysqli_error());


        Print "<select name='filtersuburb' style=width:80px>";
        Print "<option value='all'>All</option>";
        while($info1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($data1))
        {
        Print "<option value=".$info1['add2'].">".$info1['add2']."</option>";
        }

        Print "</select>";

        Print "<input type='submit'>";
        Print "</form>";




        $data2=mysqli_query($con, $_POST['filteragent']) or die(mysqli_error($con));


        Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";

        Print "<th>Address:</th><th>Suburb:</th><th>City:</th><th>Asking Price:</th><th>Number of Bathrooms:</th><th>Number of Bedrooms:</th><th>Agent:</th>";

        while($info2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($data2))
        {
        Print "<tr>";
        Print "<td>".$info2['add1']."</td>";
        Print "<td>".$info2['add2']."</td>";
        Print "<td>".$info2['add3']."</td>";
        Print "<td>$".$info2['price']."</td>";
        Print "<td>".$info2['bath']."</td>";
        Print "<td>".$info2['bed']."</td>";
        Print "<td>".$info2['agent']."</td>";
        }

        Print "</table>";

    ?></p>



    </div>


    <div id="footer">

    </div>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: mysqli_connect indicates MySql.

Answer (score 0):

```
Print '<option value="$sql1")>J Blades</option>';
```

You're not actually making a query here, you've just assigned text to a variable.

Edit:

You've got a long way to go to make this work right, but hopefully this will fix what you think is wrong:

```
    ..........
Print "<form action='listingsstaff.php' method='post'>";
    Print "Agent";
    Print "<select name='filteragent'>";
    Print "<option value=\"SELECT * FROM tblhousingstock\">All</option>";
    Print "<option value=\"SELECT * FROM tblhousingstock WHERE agent='J Blades'\">J Blades</option>";
    Print "<option value=\"SELECT * FROM tblhousingstock WHERE agent='D Astle'\">D Astle</option>";
    Print "<option value=\"SELECT * FROM tblhousingstock WHERE agent='M Smith'\">M Smith</option>";
    Print "</select>";
    Print "Suburb";
    ..........
```

I'm just changing the way you enclosed the select statements with quotes and double quotes.

Comment: The variable is used later in the code in a query. Do you know what I've done incorrectly?
    $data2=mysqli_query($con, $_POST['filteragent']) or die(mysqli_error($con));